# Chrome generating multiple requests for ASP.NET web forms page

Tags: asp.net

I am having problems with Chrome generating multiple requests for ASP.NET web forms page. From reading other posts, it seems that possible causes for this would be blank image src's, extensions, etc. The page I am playing with has absolutely nothing--please see below. However, Chrome generates (at least) 3 requests every time the page is called. Also, not only the page is requested 3 times, but the first two requests seems to come from Firefox, and he 3rd request seems to come from Chrome.

I was able to reproduce the issue with the simple page below:

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>Loaded</h1>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code behind (so that I can see where the requests are coming from, and how many times the requests are generated):

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string logFile = "LoadCountFromTest" + Request.Browser.Browser + ".txt";
        logFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(logFile);

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logFile, true);

        sw.WriteLine("********** {0} ********** {1} ******* {2} ****** {3}", Request.IsLocal, Request.Browser.Browser, DateTime.Now, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath.ToString());

        sw.Close();

    }
```

As you can see, there is nothing special about this. When I run the above, these are the contents of the files ("LoadCountFromTestFirefox" and "LoadCountFromTestChrome"):

1. LoadCountFromTestFirefox:

********** True ********** Firefox ******* 5/20/2015 2:46:28 PM ****** /Test.aspx

********** True ********** Firefox ******* 5/20/2015 2:46:28 PM ****** /Test.aspx

2. LoadCountFromTestChrome:

********** True ********** Chrome ******* 5/20/2015 2:46:28 PM ****** /Test.aspx

Again, the above only happens in Chrome... everything is fine in IE and Firefox.

Ideas? I do appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Thanks,

```
2015-05-20 23:23:33 ::1 GET /Test.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrom‌​e/42.0.2311.152+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 4
2015-05-20 23:23:34 ::1 HEAD /Test.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+x86_64;+rv:10.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/10.0+(Chrome) 200 0 0 4 
2015-05-20 23:23:34 ::1 GET /Test.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+x86_64;+rv:10.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/10.0+(Chrome) 200 0 0 2
```

Comment: I'd like to add that I have disabled all extensions as suggested in other posts to no avail. Also, the above issue only happens the first time the pages is requested... subsequent requests are fine.

Comment: What do your actual webserver logs say?

Comment: Also, please post the actual rendered HTML, not just the ASPX.

Comment: Dai, there isn't much about the rendered HTML -- as you can see the the code above, it only renders "Loaded." This is what I see in the logs:

2015-05-20 23:23:33 ::1 GET /Test.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/42.0.2311.152+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 4
2015-05-20 23:23:34 ::1 HEAD /Test.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+x86_64;+rv:10.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/10.0+(Chrome) 200 0 0 4
2015-05-20 23:23:34 ::1 GET /Test.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+x86_64;+rv:10.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/10.0+(Chrome) 200 0 0 2

Thanks.

Comment: OK. Thanks. The question is why? Why is it using both Firefox and Chrome user agents? How can this be prevented?

Comment: Sorry, it was Firefox making the HEAD request, not Chrome. I think this thread explains why: http://serverfault.com/questions/653715/head-requests-from-linux-ubuntu-boxes - I see that Firefox is running in Linux, which is the same scenario in that linked question. Are you running any form of proxy or caching system on or between the Linux box and your webserver?

Comment: No  Linux here.. 100% WIndows.

Comment: Then why is your Firefox User-Agent string reporting "`X11;+Linux+x86_64;+rv:10.0`"?

Comment: Yeah, that is the question! Even if I switch the user agent to something else, the Linux Firefox is always there??!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome menu, under More Tools, open up the Developer Tools and you should see a tab for Sources. See what all is there? Also, there's a Network tab that should show you what Chrome is doing when you reload the page.

It sounds like it's not abnormal for Chrome to generate multiple requests ([See this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/A415fHudhhM), [and this one](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/9nt0cKW2680)). One reason is apparently due to it trying to retrieve `favicon.ico`, but I think that that should show up in your web server logs and it looks like that's not the case.

Comment: What I have under Sources is basically the same HTML I have above, along with the ViewState. Under Network I only see the Chrome request... Firefox requests are nowhere to be found.....

Comment: The thing is, even the "Firefox" requests say Chrome towards the end of the user agent string. `+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/10.0+(Chrome)` I'm thinking that this has to be something that Chrome is trying to do to "optimize" network traffic or something.

Comment: That is also my assumption, although it has been difficult to confirm. I just posted the same issue to the Chrome Forum, and I hope someone will be able to shed some light on it. I would like to think that someone else has had the same issue before. Thanks.